# Dropdowns with subtitle and buttons on the right side

Tags: html, css

I have two dropdown items next to each other in a container (`select-container`). I want to have a subtitle (`sub-container`) below this container. Next to the container more buttons should appear. If the screen size is to large the buttons should float to the next line - but stay on the right side.

I tried to create a wrapper (`div`) around everything, set `display:flex` and the buttons wrapped in a container with `display:inline-flex` but didn't succeed very much. I tried as well the `button-container` with

```
{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center; 
}
```

but didn't succeed since the subtitle start floating around.

Any hint how to structure the HTML (and CSS) properly? Just a side note: normally the space on the right is sufficient but sometimes it to less ==> I want to have them wrapped on the right side only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="options">
      <select name="opt1">
        <option>Value 1</option>
        <option>Value 2</option>
        <option>Value 3</option>
        <option>Value 4</option>
      </select>
      <select name="opt2">
        <option>Value 1</option>
        <option>Value 2</option>
        <option>Value 3</option>
        <option>Value 4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, iusto?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/QWGjgWK

Comment: Thx - this is close to what I'm looking for. Is there a way to let `Button1` and `Button2` stay next to each other (=same line). If there is not enough space they should wrap. If the space after wrapping is again to small ==> start wrapping `options`. With the current config the `options` are wrapped first (which isn't the way I'm looking for).

Comment: @LeO you can use `media queries` to achieve it.

Comment: Hmmm... well - since this depends on the length of the text and the options its hard to know in advance. I thought perhaps with `flex-grow` or `flex-shrink` it could work. But didn't succeed.